# Why doesn't resultSet next doesn't return any value from my oracle SQL database, even though initiating the same command inside sql developer works?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to get a values from database so I can check them inside the while loop but the rsRoles.next() returns false even before anything happens.

This is my table:

```
Name                 Null?    Type       
-------------------- -------- ---------- 
USER_ID_USER         NOT NULL NUMBER(38) 
ROLE_ID_ROLE         NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
```

And this are its values:

```
USER_ID_USER | ROLE_ID_ROLE                
-------------|-------------
3            |  1
3            |  2
```

I used this query inside oracle database:

```sql
SELECT user_id_user, role_id_role
FROM user_roles
WHERE user_id_user=3;
```

This statement returns the table above, which is correct. Although when I do this in my Java code:

```java
Connection conn = database.getConnection();

String getRoles = "SELECT role_id_role, user_id_user\n"
                    + "FROM user_roles\n"
                    + "WHERE user_id_user=?";

            PreparedStatement prstm = conn.prepareStatement(getRoles);

            prstm.setInt(1, ManageUsersDialogController.getEditingUser().getAccountID());

            ResultSet rsRoles = prstm.executeQuery();

            while (rsRoles.next()) { // returns false

                int role = rsRoles.getInt("role_id_role");

                switch (role) {
                    case 1:
                        checkBoxAdmin.setSelected(true);
                        adminWasSelected = true;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        checkBoxTeacher.setSelected(true);
                        teacherWasSelected = true;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        checkBoxStudent.setSelected(true);
                        studentWasSelected = true;

                }
```

it never gets into the while cycle.

What could be the issue?

Comment: What is the issue that you see?  An error?  If so, what?  Incorrect data?  If so, what?

Comment: Are you sure you committed your data, and that you are connected to the right database? What value does `ManageUsersDialogController.getEditingUser().getAccountID()` return?

Comment: @GordonLinoff No error, rsRoles.next() just returns false as if there are no data. And it just skips to the next step, while cycle never starts.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it returns 3 as it should. I am sure I am connected to the right database, as all the other values that I am returning previously in the application are returned correctly.

Comment: What happens if you hardcode `3` in the query instead of using a parameter? If that also returns nothing, then you are either connecting to a different database, or your other session is looking at uncommitted data.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Still the same behaviour, rsRoles.next() returns false and while cycle never starts.

Comment: The documentation of the oracle JDBC Driver says that the PL/SQL Type `NUMBER` is mapped to `java.math.BigDecimal` ( https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm ). Have you tried querying using `BigDecimal`?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel So I think I have found the issue, the problem is that I somehow "locked" the table. Whenever I click "drop table" I get error saying "table is busy" so I think that some query is still running. However I have no idea how to fix that issue as I am not the administrator of the database. The administrator of the database is my lecturer. So I can't run the "kill tasks" command inside the oracle sql developer.  

I also tried to disconnect from connection, reconnecting to school VPN but nothing works, the table is still "stuck".

Answer (score 0):

The reason this didn't work was because said table was busy. So I couldn't enter data via code and neither could I see data that I had in the database (because it was not committed even though it said it has been committed.

The solution that I came across was that once I gave up I suddenly got like 10 popup messages from IDE as well as database saying that connection has been stopped, so I guess timeout did its work.